# Allow only phrasing content in CKEditor textarea mode

Tags: ckeditor

With HTML editors such as ckeditor, there seems to be a convention to distinguish between editing HTML inside `<textarea/>` content, and »inline« editing via contenteditable.

When doing the latter, the editor automatically recognizes the difference between elements that allow flow content (i.e. `<div/>`) and such ones that only allow phrasing content (i.e. `<p/>`) and allows only valid elements inside the respective contenteditable.

I need a way to edit HTML inside of a `<textarea/>` with ckeditor, while allowing only phrasing content. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can implement almost every behavior using ckeditor configuration, take a look into https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/?mobile=/guide/dev_acf

Comment: I tried `CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent="a[*]";`, but it still allows p tags

Answer (score 0):

I found a bit of a hack way of doing this. I looked up `CKEDITOR.inline()` in the source tree in `ckeditor-dev/core/creators/inline.js`. The existing code automatically creates a `<div/>` tag if you want to inline-edit a `<textarea/>`

Then I monkey patched it to accept an additional string argument, which determines the name of the automatically created contenteditable element, which is otherwise hardcoded to be a `<div/>`.